# Wix Toolset - Is there a way to validate silent install property values

Tags: wix

What I'd like to do is to validate property values entered on msiexec /QN calls.

As an example, for our runtime SQL Server database authentication, we need to offer Windows Authentication and SQL User Authentication.  I represent these with a RadioButtonGroup on a UI Dialog window.  The default value, for the "RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE" property, going through the UI is "SqlAuth".

For silent installs, I'd like to:

1) Set a default value of the "RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE" property to "SqlAuth", if the user enters no value for the "RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE" property on the silent install command line.

2) Check a launch condition that would fail if the value of the "RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE" property is set to something other than "SqlAuth or "WinAuth" (case insensitive).

My code (located in my equivalent of the product.wxs file):

```
<SetProperty Id="RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE" Value="SqlAuth" Before="LaunchConditions" Sequence="both">NOT RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE</SetProperty>
<Condition Message="!(loc.RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE_Messg)">RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE ~= "SqlAuth" OR RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE ~= "WinAuth"</Condition>
```

When building the WiX MSI package I get the following error:

[exec] D:\stuff\scripts\testNG\installation\wix_installer\dialogs\TenantDBConnectDlg.wxs(23) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE' in section 'Fragment:'.

Is there a way to do this type of validation in WiX?

Answer (score 0):

Looks I solved my own question; at least for Wix RadioButtonGroup elements.

In my product.wxs equivalent file, I just add these two lines

```
<Property Id="RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE" Value="SqlAuth" />
<Condition Message="!(loc.RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE_Messg)">RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE ~= "SqlAuth" OR RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE ~= "WinAuth"</Condition>
```

In the log file, everything works as I'd like.  The RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE:

1) Gets set to the value in the property element
2) Gets overridden by a value entered on the command line (e.g. RT_DB_LOGON_TYPE= foo
3) Gets evaluated in the launch condition, which is captured in the log file.

Note: I found no visual clues to this failure outside of the log file.